# Modifying this Excel Formula to include 'OR'

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need to change this Excel formula by including the OR statement in it.

Actually it stands like this:

```
=IF(D18=0,"NA",(D17-D18)/D18))
```

I need it to become:

```
IF D18=0 OR D18="NA", THEN "NA", ELSE (D17-D18)/D18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(D18=0,D18="NA"),"NA",(D17-D18)/D18)
```

In Excel, you use `OR` and `AND` as functions like above, instead of doing something like `x=A OR x=B` as is done in most programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to shree.pat18's answer:

If by `NA` you mean the Excel error for `N/A!`, this formula will work:

```
=IF(OR(D18=0,ISNA(D18)),NA(),(D17-D18)/D18)
```